Is it common in Western countries to attack politicians over the[ir] lack of biological children? And is it a winning argument?
Is it common in Western countries to attack politicians over the[ir] lack of biological children? And is it a winning argument in front of the electorate?

In the United States, at least, conservative pundits, candidates, and commentators will frequently (though not what I would say 'often' which would suggest a majority of the time) remark on various attributes of their female opponents along lines of their marital status, whether or not they have children, and in ways critical of their opponents' professional record.
All of these have in common that they are invoking what the Republican Party has typically referred to as Traditional Family Values (TFV). Central to this paradigm is the idea that the role of women is as child bearers and homemakers. Under this paradigm, women who are unmarried are failing in their role as child bearers because heterosexual (typically Christian) marriage is the only legitimate condition under which children should be born and reared. Women who are married, but have no children, are almost as bad because they're making a mockery of the presumptive purpose of matrimony (to provide the conditions for children to be born into).  Women who have jobs outside of the home, and especially those women who seek positions of power and authority, are also putative traitors to their purpose in society as they are usurping roles exclusively intended for men.
The pattern plays out time and time again.  This go round rhymes with the similar rise in such rhetoric when Reagan was running for President in that the Republic slate has a number of embarrassing and otherwise damaging points in the foreign policy sphere and so they shift their rhetoric towards the domestic.
As to how effective it is, as with almost all political speech, it's highly effective with audiences who subscribe to the 'Traditional Family Values' paradigm. It is also effective, but in the opposite direction, for those who find 'TFV' to be objectionable (most liberals).
It's purpose is mainly a form of virtue signaling, meant to appease the base and help insulate them from messaging the opponent might send.  In this case it's especially aimed at conservative women, whose identity is on the line as table stakes in 'TFV' and so who are both receptive to having their identity reinforced AND are vulnerable to messaging that Harris might be able to slip past typical filters because of a shared identity as women.
It doesn't move the needle, but it's not meant to - it's a measure to stop the needle from moving.

Does [US] TFV exclude adopted children? Because it sounds to me like this is more than TFV. More like "man or woman CURSED by GOD", so unworthy of ... everything? Or at least of any noteworthy position in society.

@timetakesitstoll I'm not familiar with the specific nuances of Republican political thought or Christian ideological subtleties, myself.  But the answer is probably "it depends on the speaker/audience/context."

You're probably right, but this seems like an extremely risky tactic if used prominently.  As useful as H. Clinton's deplorables :  speaks to the base, turns everyone else off.  Women tend to take broad criticism of women badly, are already upset with abortion issues and have long resented having to choose between child-rearing and careers.

But, pls note that this seems to have been Vance-as-private-citizen some time back, not Vance-as-VP-candidate now, a context which is entirely missing from the Q.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: why would I put it in the Q? I tried to steer away from a specific example. I want to know if it's messaging that works, more broadly. And AFAICT Vance was a Senate candidate then, so that was not exactly an apolitical comment of his. https://edition.cnn.com/2024/07/28/politics/trump-harris-election-100-days/index.html

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: There's some footage here from that interview. He had his own "Vance" campaign posters in the background as he was saying that.

Older people with no children have very little skin in the game.
If you have an MP with children, they would probably want to see them thrive and succeed, even though there are dangers of nepotism. However, when a candidate does not have any children, it's not apparent why they won't do dangerous, irresponsible things.
A special case for developing countries is when a candidate has children, but they happen to live in another country, thus sparking concerns of whether the politician and their family is going to experience the change they may bring, or be shielded from it.

People with adopted children have skin in the game. The question is specifically about biological children (because Kamala Harris has been criticized by Vance for being childless, but she has two adopted children).
